# Add a lateral Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

Hi I've a gridlayout in my frame with inside two other Jpanel with also gridlayout. Now I want add a Jpanel on rigth side that occupy space vertically from top to down.
How can I do ?

```
container = frame.getContentPane();
matricepc = new JPanel();
matrice = new JPanel();
matrice.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));
matricepc.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
container.add(matricepc);
container.add(matrice);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `matricepc` and `matrice` inside a `JPanel` with the `GridLayout`, instead of the `JFrame`. Put the `JPanel` at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the `JFrame` then add your other right `JPanel` to the `BorderLayout.EAST`

```
container = frame.getContentPane();
matricepc = new JPanel();
matrice = new JPanel();
matrice.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));
matricepc.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));

//container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));             <--+
//container.add(matricepc);                                |-- Remove this code
//container.add(matrice);                               <--+

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));   <--+
centerPanel.add(matricepc);                                |
centerPanel.add(matrice);                                  |
container.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);           |-- Add this code
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();                          |
container.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);           <--+
```

Comment: Yes I've do it but I have a NullExecptionPointer at view.PartitaView.<init>(PartitaView.java:49), that is line :JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: Did you take out the last three lines of your code?

Comment: That line should not throw a `NullPinterException`, _anywhere_ you use it in the entire galaxy.

Comment: BTW - there is no way that code line could produce a `NullPointerException`, you are apparently reading the stack trace wrong, or equating it with the wrong code line.